# How to pass values by POST in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I have problem with passing values by POST in ASP.NET MVC 4 
This is my action in User controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Show(int? uid, string uname)
{
    return uname + uid.ToString();
}
```

And this is how I tried to pass values in view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Show", "User"))
{
    Html.Hidden("uid", Model.Id);
    Html.Hidden("uname", Model.UserName);
    <input type="submit" value="+"/>
}
```

html:

```
 <form action="/User/Show" method="post"> <input type="submit" value="+"/> </form>
```

and:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Show", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { uid = 1, uname = "user1" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="+"/>
}
```

html:

```
<form action="/User/Show" method="post" uid="1" uname="user1"> <input type="submit" value="+"/></form>
```

In both ways Show action receives null instead real values.

Comment: Is it possible that the values Model.Id and Model.UserName is actually null? Can you copy-paste yout HTML source of your form, as rendered in the browser? Probably unlikely but just to check.

Comment: It's impossible because I also tried with hardcoded variables. 
`<form action="/User/Show" method="post">                <input type="submit" value="+"/>`

`</form><form action="/User/Show" method="post" uid="1" uname="user1">                <input type="submit" value="+"/>`

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see any hidden input fields in there. Also, can you add your source to the main body of your question.

Comment: Just so you know, you can't just add attributes to the `<form>` tag like that, correct method is `<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="1" />` etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your HtmlHelpers are not being rendered. Use Razor syntax.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Show", "User"))
{
    @Html.Hidden("uid", Model.Id);
    @Html.Hidden("uname", Model.UserName);
    <input type="submit" value="+"/>
}
```

Explanation:

Calling `Html.Hidden` (or `Html.[anything]`) is a method and usually returns an `IHtmlString`. Without using `@` infront, the engine doesn't know that you're trying to output the returned string. It just thinks you're calling a method.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good approach for an action that receives data<strike>. This approach can offer many security breaches, like data injection.</strike>, essentially lots of fields.

The right thing is create a Model (or a ViewModel, if you don't want to persist the data) to make the correct guidance between View and Controller:

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public int? uid { get; set; }
    public string uname { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Show", "User"))
{
    Html.HiddenFor(model => model.uid);
    Html.HiddenFor(model => model.uname);
    <input type="submit" value="+"/>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Show(int modelId) {
    var model = context.Model.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ModelId == modelId);
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();

    viewModel.uid = model.Id;
    viewModel.uname = model.UserName;

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public string Show(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    return viewMode.uname + viewModel.uid.ToString();
}
```

Comment: A ViewModel doesn't prevent injection problems. If you have many values being passed in a ViewModel is certainly convenient, but whether it's a ViewModel or discrete values it still runs through the model binder.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually creating hidden fields in your form. You need the @ in front of you Hidden helper, and drop the semi-colon at the end.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Show", "User"))
{
    @Html.Hidden("uid", Model.Id)
    @Html.Hidden("uname", Model.UserName)
    <input type="submit" value="+"/>
}
```

The reason your hard-coded test didn't work is that your HTML wasn't correct. You can't just put the values you want to post on the `<form>` element, you need to have them as hidden fields in the form.

```
<form action="/User/Show" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="uname" value="user1">
    <input type="submit" value="+"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could use a view model.

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
   public int? Id {get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Show()
{
    return View(new MyViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Show(MyViewModel model)
{
    return Content(string.format("{0} - {1}", model.Id, model.UserName));
}
```

(Coded in notepad so untested, but should work.)